# A regex for detecting multiline text if ended with a character

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, macros, multiline

I have a parser that parses through code of the PAWN language.

I already have a regex that parses for defines in that code, A typical define looks like:

```
#define DEFINE_NAME DEFINE_VALUE
```

And I use the following regex to detect it:

```
#define[ \t]+([^\n\r\s\\;]+)(?:[ \t]*([^\s;]+))?
```

Now to the actual problem.. The PAWN language allows multiple lines only if each line ended with slash.. So this would be valid:

```
#define DEFINE_NAME \
    DEFINE_VALUE    \
    CONTINUE_VALUE
```

And can keeps going if there is more slashes.

Soo.. I would like a regex that can capture possible multi-line stuff like this.

> NOTE: I also need it to work in single line defines.. So please keep that in mind.
>
> Also I use .NET, So yes that's the flavor.

Any help/contribution is very appreciated. :D

Comment: Just wondering - is PAWN a regular language?  While you may be able to parse simple statements like the `#define` in your example, you may find it becomes increasingly difficult to use regexes as you progress.  Typically things are done using a tokeniser / parser.

Comment: I got an [ugly regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23define%5cb%5b%5e%5cn%5c%5c%5d*(%3f%3a%5c%5c%5cr%3f%5cn.%2b)*(%3f%3a%5cn.*)%3f&i=%23define+DEFINE_NAME+%5c%0d%0a++++DEFINE_VALUE++++%5c%0d%0a++++CONTINUE_VALUE%0d%0a%0d%0aSome+more%0d%0a%0d%0a%23define+DEFINE_NAME+DEFINE_VALUE) after some attempts, maybe it can help you start. Perhaps, it will convince you to just write an own little efficient parser.

Comment: Are you forbidding the use of inline comments?

Comment: It's a simple type less scripting language.. So regex will just work great.  Plus it's a parser for an IDE not a compiler.

Comment: I think the below answer nailed it, just need to test it.

Comment: And Andre, i want it to goto the new line only if there is a slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can include the optional slash and newline with:

```
(?:\\\r?\n[ \t]*)?
```

Then, to allow multiple lines ended with a slash, we can repeat the following construct:

```
(?<value>(?>                  # Captures the DEFINE_VALUE
    [^\\\r\n;]+               #   Any char (except \ \n)
  |                           #  or
    \\[^\r\n][^\\\r\n;]*      #   "\" within value
)+)?                          #  (~unrolling the loop)
(?:\\\r?\n[ \t]*)?            # allow "\" for new line
```

---

**Code**

```vb
Dim pattern As String = "^[ \t]*                    # beginning of line     " & vbCrLf &
                        "[#]define[ \t]+            # PAWN #define          " & vbCrLf &
                        "(?<name>[^\s\\;]+)         # DEFINE_NAME           " & vbCrLf &
                        "[ \t]*(?:\\\r?\n[ \t]*)?   # spaces and optional \ " & vbCrLf &
                        "(?>                        #                       " & vbCrLf &
                        "  (?<value>(?>             # DEFINE_VALUE          " & vbCrLf &
                        "    [^\\\r\n;]+   |        #  Any char -except \ \n" & vbCrLf &
                        "    \\[^\r\n][^\\\r\n;]*   #  \ within value       " & vbCrLf &
                        "  )+)?                     #  (~unrolling the loop)" & vbCrLf &
                        "  (?:\\\r?\n[ \t]*)?       # \ for new line        " & vbCrLf &
                        ")*                         # repeated for each line"

Dim re As Regex = new Regex( pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline Or
                                      RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
Dim text As String =    "#define DEFINE_NAME \"     & vbCrLf &
                        "       DEFINE VALUE\"      & vbCrLf &
                        "       CONTINUE VALUE"     & vbCrLf &
                        "#define TheName TheValue"
Dim mNum As Integer = 0
Dim matches As MatchCollection = re.Matches(text)

'Loop Matches
For Each match As Match In matches
    'get name
    Dim name As String = match.Groups("name").Value
    Console.WriteLine("Match #{0} - Name: {1}", mNum, name)

    'get values (in each capture)
    Dim captureCtr As Integer = 0
    For Each capture As Capture In match.Groups("value").Captures
        'loop captures for the Group "value"
        Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "Line #{0} - Value: {1}", 
                                captureCtr, capture.Value)
        captureCtr += 1              
    Next
    mNum += 1
Next
```

**Output**

```
Match #0 - Name: DEFINE_NAME
    Line #0 - Value: DEFINE_VALUE
    Line #1 - Value: CONTINUE_VALUE
Match #1 - Name: TheName
    Line #0 - Value: TheValue
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ntgwWk)</kbd>

---

- Notice I'm using the [named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) `(?<name>..)` and `(?<value>..)`. That's why it's referenced in the code as [`match.Groups("name")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Moreover, the group `(?<value>[^\s;]+)` is repeated for each line. And `Groups("value")` contains information about the last captured substring. But the **[Captures property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx)** contains information about all the substrings captured by the group. This is a unique [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) feature.
  That's why I'm looping `match.Groups("value").Captures`.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.. You are a regex beast.

I had to modify it a little to support whitespace in value though, Here is my final regex: 
`^[ \t]*[#]define[ \t]+(?<name>[^\s\\;]+)[ \t]*(?:\\\s+)?(?>(?<value>[^\\\n\r]+)[ \t]*(?:\\\s+)?)*`

Comment: @Ahmad45123 That was intentional, because I assumed that from your first attempt `([^\s;]+)`, as it wasn't clear what was supposed to be the correct syntax for a `#define`. I edited the answer to account for spaces now in the value. Check the updated regex.

Comment: Yeah that was a bug in my regex, my apologies :P
And thanks again.